# why is string not printing the desired output in c++?

Tags: c++

I am writing this piece of code in c++.

```
std::string s;
s[0] = 'a';
std::cout << s;
```

Result should be : a

Why is this no printing anything ? Question is trivial but can anyone explain in a better way.

Comment: I am recommending you to visit http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string s; // s is default constructed (s.length() returns 0)
//s[0] = 'a'; // modifying elements that are out of bounds causes undefined behavior
s.resize(1);
s[0] = 'a'; // OK, s.length() is 1
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 7):

Your string size is zero from start so you are not allowed to access index zero. Instead do

```
s = "a";
```

Now the string has size 1 and It is allowed to access s[0]

In general you may index from zero to size-1 but only when size >= 1